# How do i disable the button after its been clicked a certain amount of times discord js

Tags: discord, discord.js

so basically, i would pass a number as an argument and i want to disable the button after it was clicked that many times.
However, when i use this code, it returns how many times it has been clicked but it doesnt disable the button.

```
message.channel.send({
    content: "Click on the button below to enroll for fate adventure!",
    components: [row],
  });

  const filter = (m) => m.customId === "enrollButton";
  const collector = message.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({
    filter: filter,
    max: parseInt(args[1]),
    time: 15000,
  });

  collector.on("collect", (i) => {
    i.reply(`Clicked`);
  });

  collector.on("end", (collected) => {
    row.components[0].setDisabled(true);
    message.channel.send(`Clicked ${collected.size} times`);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply EDIT the message with everything keeping it the same but with the button edited to be disabled. For example:

```js
collector.on("end", collected => {
  collected.first().message.edit({
    components: collected.first().message.components
      .map(c => c.map(c => c.setDisabled(true)))
  })
});
```

Comment: but wouldn't that disable the button after one click?
Also it gives me an error: TypeError: c.setDisabled is not a function

Comment: i still get c.map is not a function

Answer (score 0):

One way to give your code context of how many times the button has been pressed is to add a property to your client.

```js
client.buttonClicks = 0;
```

And increment it on the collect event. Then, check if the limit has been reached. If so, end the collector and disable the button.

```js
collector.on("collect", (i) => {
    i.reply(`Clicked`);
    client.buttonClicks++;

    if (client.buttonClicks == LIMIT) {
        collector.end("limit");
    }
});

collector.on("end", (collected) => {
    // Disable here
});
```

Comment: apparently collecter.end() is not a function